# Unity3d: How to receive input from HTTP

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to ask you if there is any way in Unity to receive the input from HTTP calls (if not HTTP I'm interested in any way of controlling the game process by another process on the same machine).

To be clear, if there is a way to make it serverless (client-only with the option of receiving some control from the outside of the process) it will be the preferred option for me.

Comment: Have you tried any of the standard C# HTTP utilities, such at `HttpClient`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @rhughes while HttpClient would be perfect for making a HTTP call from the Unity game process to some web api, I'm interested in opposite direction, receiving HTTP calls in the game process.

Comment: So you don't want to use TCP/UDP? What about polling a HTTP service?

Comment: Do you mean HTTP service hosted in the game process? @rhughes

Comment: Use named pipes.  If named pipes are not supported in unity (I've never tried) you can put your named pipes code in a native plugin.

Comment: I'm just checking NetworkTransport from UnityEngine.Networking, it looks like opening the socket communication so with a bit of luck I could use this protocol. Now I need to find the way for connecting to this socket from node application